# "Class" does not name a type

Tags: c++

I'm current stuck on a c++ code of abstracting a calculator. Thing is I have a abstract class header to override with my own derivative. However, the compiler insist in giving me the error on the title. I already had checked all the includes and it does not seems to be wrong. Can anyone give me some light?

My header:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.hpp"

#ifndef CALCULATORIURI_H
#define CALCULATORIURI_H

class CalculatorIuri: public Calculator{
    public:
        CalculatorIuri();


        CalculatorKeyboard* getCalculatorKeyboard();
        Cpu* getCpu();
        Screen* getScreen(void);
        void receive(Operation);
        void receiveDigit(Digit);
        void receiveClear();

        int value;



};

#endif
```

The code:

```cpp
#include "CalculatorIuri.hpp"


CalculatorIuri::CalculatorIuri(){

}

Screen* CalculatorIuri::getScreen(void){

}
//and it goes on...
```

The compilator keeps telling me that "CalculatorIuri" does not name a type, but it was already declared as a class.

The original code with the pure abstract methods:

```cpp
//no includes before, just another abstract classes definitions and header guard
class Calculator: public CalculatorReceiver {
public:
  virtual CalculatorKeyboard * getCalculatorKeyboard() = 0;
  virtual Cpu * getCpu() = 0;
  virtual Screen * getScreen() = 0;
};
//and goes on...
```

edit:

Strange fact is that other derivative classes seems to work fine, like this one

```cpp
#ifndef SCREENIURI_H
#define SCREENIURI_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.hpp"

class ScreenIuri: public Screen{


    public:
        ScreenIuri();

        void clear(void);
        void addDigit(Digit);

};

#endif
```

edit2:

I just rewritten the header and for some reason it worked like the other ones, thank you everyone for the time.

New header:

```cpp
#ifndef CALCULATORIURI_H
#define CALCULATORIURI_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.hpp"

class CalculatorIuri:public Calculator{

    public:
        CalculatorIuri();
        CalculatorKeyboard * getCalculatorKeyboard();
        Cpu * getCpu();
        Screen * getScreen();
        int value;


};

#endif
```

Comment: Move `#ifndef CALCULATORIURI_H
#define CALCULATORIURI_H` save guard on top of the header file, add you incudes after guard.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Not at all Brandon, the CalculatorReceiver class was on the same Calculator file

Comment: Actually it would need the full code to really reproduce, I can make a .zip file of it if is needed

Comment: Looks like you're marching into a [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes).

Comment: Already checked it, there is no include on Calculator.hpp

Comment: Groovy, but watch out for chains of includes as well. I reiterate the request for a [mcve].

Comment: Make a [mcve] that abstracts away all the `#include`s. Hint: just copy/paste to achieve this. And if you reach a point where you're copy/pasting ad infinatum, then you've found the problem the compiler's had ;)

Comment: *"Actually it would need the full code to really reproduce"* The linked article has some suggestions on how to reduce the amount of code needed to reproduce.